# How do I get rid of a large spacing in between two containers in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a single container and row split into two columns. On the left column is a title and on the right column is a card. Both are centered. The issue I am having is when I put it in mobile view, There is an abnormally large spacing between the title, which is on top, and the card, which is underneath. I was wondering how I could fix this! Thank you for all and any help :)

```css
body,html {
  height: 150%;
  background-color:#F0F8FF;
}
.card {
  border: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 625px;
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
  border: 5px solid #81D8D0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exampleTitle{
  width: 400px;
  color: #81D8D0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border: 5px solid #81D8D0;
  box-shadow: 5px 4px 20px #81D8D0;
  margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-xl-6  align-self-center">
        <div class="exampleTitle text-center rounded">
          Title
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6  align-self-center">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would add a @media query. Can you tell us what you'd like it to look like so we can style it for you?

Comment: Why do you need the height to be 100%? If you remove h-100 for both div, the problem will be gone.

Comment: when i remove the height, the row starts from the top has a height equal to the largest column, which in this case is 625px (height of the card. Because of this I cannot center the row/column in the center of the page.

Comment: How are you expecting it to look on mobile? Just what it looks like without the h-100? If so, you can do an *inverse* media query, making h-100 100% only if the size is *greater* than whatever breakpoint you choose. If that's what you want, I can get a solution, but I want to be sure that's what you want before I start.

Comment: i want the title to be stacked on top of the card without a large space in between

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `fixed "height: 150%"` in the body html.

Try using `@media` with `"min-height: 150%"` in the html.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    html, body {
    min-height: 150%; }
}
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to erase `height: 150%;` from the CSS rule for `html, body`. This will set the height to `auto`, which should help to prevent your problem.

Comment: I have done this, but i am still experincing the same issue in the mobile version

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of solution without additional CSS.

When the width of the screen is xl, the first column (with title) will be shown but another title will be hidden.

When the width of the screen is smaller than xl, the first column will be hidden but another title will be shown.

```html
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-xl-6 align-self-center d-none d-xl-block">
        <div class="exampleTitle text-center rounded">
          Title
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 align-self-center">
        <div class="d-block d-xl-none">
            <div class="exampleTitle text-center rounded">
              Title
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```